# Assigning Permission on Azure SQL Database

Tags: permissions, azure-sql-database, users

I have an azure SQL Database. I already created a new login and user on the database. Question is i want to assign permission on the said user. Permission that will restrict the user to drop table, update data, truncate and create another role?

Comment: What do you want the user to have permissions for should be the first thing? and then the restriction. If just the read permissions than db_datareader is enough.

Comment: user cannot drop tables, alter, create/alter table, create/alter sp. user can only select data. is these possible on azure sql database?

Comment: Yes just grant db_datareader. db_datareader
Members of the db_datareader fixed database role can read all data from all user tables.

Comment: Currently i am encountering an issue saying that : 
The server principal "Test" is not able to access the database "master" under the current security context.
Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'Test'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 916)

Comment: Go to the OPTIONS  tab --> connection properties --> Connect to Database  Provide the name of the database. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19094970/how-do-i-create-a-new-user-in-a-sql-azure-database

Answer (score 0):

I do not have an azure database server right now to check, but looking at the regular SQL server instance it is pretty easy. I hope, or think it is the same for an azure DB
If you have created the user already, then you can map the user to the database.

CREATE USER [User] FOR LOGIN [user]

It will get public access automatically, meaning it can connect to the database.
With this public access not much can be done, but to give extra 
Easy way to grant only read access on the complete database is to grant db_datareader access.

on the DB in a query

ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [User]

If per table access is needed, you need to play with the security within the database itself.
for example
Connect to the database you want to do security

DENY DELETE ON [schema].[tablename] TO [user]

Comment: Currently i am encountering an error saying that : 
The server principal "Test" is not able to access the database "master" under the current security context.
Cannot open user default database. Login failed.
Login failed for user 'Test'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 916)